# The properties window changed its layout to landscape

Tags: interface

[image]
I have a UI problem: the "properties" window changed into landscape format for some reason.

How can I fix it, without reloading the factory settings?

Comment: Place the cursor where you need to zoom and press ctrl and (+numpad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click right of the property tab title, roughly here:

[image]

Select *Vertical* from the dialog that appears.

Comment: thank alot it fix,
trying so hard to search the answer but i dont know what keyword should i use.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this community, I wont do it again thank alot.

Comment: No need to apologize Warodom :) Welcome to BSE